# how can i ckeditor in form that i created?

Tags: python, django

I create a form with input and text area fields. As models, I have:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

description = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True,null=True,config_name='default')
```

but in the template that I used the form tag, the textarea isn't showing as an editor:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="title" required
    <textarea name="text" cols="50" rows="15" required></textarea>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add CKEditor on any-kind of Html form you want all you want to that, call the hosted version or download JavaScript pack of CKEditor to your Html or PHP Page.

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.5/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Now you need to convert the Text-area to CKEditor. For that you have to add the below JavaScript under the Text-area which you want to transform to CKEditor.

```
<textarea name="text" id="text">This is a demo .</textarea><script> CKEDITOR.replace( 'text' );</script>
```

Now you need to change the “text” from the JavaScript with the name of the Text-area.